# Android studio - new Activity with Fragment (XML files explanation)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I want to create a new Activity in Android Studio with `MainActivity` as a parent. Although, when I create a blank activity (ex. `NewActivity`) with a fragment added I get the two expected classes
(`NewActivity` and `NewActivityFragment`) but when I check the layout resources, I can't understand why there are 3 XML files auto-generated and what's their meaning?

- What is the exact meaning of each XML-file generated ? The 3 XML files are the following : **activity_new.xml**, **fragment_new.xml** and **content_new.xml**

For example , if i want to add a `TextView` in the second activity, which XML file shall i modify?

Comment: can you post some code which you are trying?

Comment: it's not like i am trying something specific, i just want to understand the meaning of each of these XML files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a New activity with a Fragment using the wizard in Android Studio, it will generate two **src** files :

- NewActivity.java
- NewActivityFragment.java

and three **res** files:

- activity_new.xml
- content_new.xml
- fragment_new.xml

The details goes as below:

1. The activity class NewActivity.java inflates the layout activity_new.xml in onCreate() method as below.

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
   This layout is a CoordinatorLayout and contains the Appbarlayout, FAB and the container for your main comonents.
2. activity_new.xml includes another layout using include tag.
3. content_new.xml is a fragment xml file and contains the attributes  to define its layouts.
   observer that content_new.xml has an attribute as below

   tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new"
4. fragment_new.xml is the layout which gets inflated in NewActivityFragment onCreateView() method.

   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new, container, false);

**fragment_new.xml** is the layout file that is the place where you go for adding the components to be shown in the fragment. So as per your requirement of adding a `TextView` in the fragment you need to add it in fragment_new.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you check activity_new.xml, you will see an `<include>` tag calling the content_new.xml.